# Order by id doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a trouble with order by in my mysql query. Without " WHERE `adder`='$followuser' " is query working fine.But with WHERE is ORDER BY not working. Can you help me please? :)
Here's my code:

```
$time=time();
$checkfollowing=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `follow` WHERE `follower`='$session'") or die(mysql_error()); /* Check if is user following somebody */

if(mysql_num_rows($checkfollowing) == FALSE){ /* He's following no one */
    echo "You follow noone";
    die();
}elseif(mysql_num_rows($checkfollowing) == TRUE){ /* He's following somebody */
    while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($checkfollowing)){
$followuser=$row11['get_follow'];

$fcontent=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `followcontent` WHERE `adder`='$followuser' ORDER BY id DESC") or die (mysql_error()); /* Follow content */

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($fcontent)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $photourl=$row['photourl'];
    $adder=$row['adder'];



    echo "<hr class='style'><br><div id='newadder'>".$adder."</div><a href='photo/?id=".$id."'><img src='".$photourl."' class='newfolimg'></a>";


}
```

}
    }

Thank you a lot :))

Comment: Post some sample data from your table.

Comment: Here is table: s23.postimg.org/fk7zkq6mj/table.png And here is result: s13.postimg.org/6z86sm0h3/result.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the data type of your `id` is `string` then it will be sorted in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Try this trick,

```
ORDER BY id * 1 ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e18/2)

MySQL will implicitly convert the column into a number. If it happens that the value starts with a letter, the corresponding value will be `0`.

Comment: BTW, is there not any function available to convert the type ?

Comment: Have never figured that out  - it all seemed okay

Comment: @SheikhHeera `CAST(id AS SIGNED)` -- is that what you mean? [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2e18/3)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately no change in result

Comment: @491243, Thanks! So, is that applicable like this way `ORDER BY CAST(id AS SIGNED) ASC` ?

Comment: @user2808698 please give us additional information, or show us sample records.

Comment: @491243 What do you think with "additional information"? Only next thing I know, I have two made users I follow, first: admin, second: z. Mysql ranks these two users from a-z. Basicly, content added by admin is everytime first. And there's no change if there is ASC or DESC.

Answer (score 0):

Probably WHERE clause limits the result to one row,that`s why is "not working".

Comment: Can you show me how is looking correct script? I'm sorry, I'm only 15 and I'm not working with php a long time :))

Comment: Post a screenshot of your table data

Comment: Ok.
Here is table: http://s23.postimg.org/fk7zkq6mj/table.png
And here is result: http://s13.postimg.org/6z86sm0h3/result.png

Comment: Add more rows with adder =z.Post the results.

Comment: Try removing id='newadder'

Comment: Remove the row with adder=admin

Comment: What does it display?

Comment: Only content from user z.

Comment: WHERE `adder`='$followuser' this line-what is in $followuser?z?If so how is the admin image displayed?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I thought row in table. Without this line it show result 3 times.